# Compile contracts that call each other

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I have two contracts, one is a Admin, other is subject. To keep things simple I am just including the functions that are invoked in the contracts relating to each other.

```
contract Subject {
  uint public count = 0;

  function increaseCount() returns newCount{
    count ++;
    newCount = count;
  }
}
```

The subject contract has a counter that can be increased via a direct call from `web3.js` or from `Master` contract.

```
contract Master {
  bool public isActive=false;
  uint public num=0;

  function changeState() returns bool newState{
    isActive = !isActive;
    newState = isActive;
  }

  function increaseSubjectCount(subjectAddr) returns uint newCount{
    SubjectContract subjectContract = SubjectContract(subjectAddr);
    newCount = ubjectAddr.increaseCount();
  }
}
```

so a transaction is fired to `Master` contract (once it is made of course) along with sufficient amount of gas. This function then uses the gas to call `increaseCount()` function in the `Subject` contract which returns the new counter. This in turn gets returned by the `Master` contract via `web3.js`. The issue I face is if I use browser solidity to compile the `Master` contract, it throws an error saying SubjectContract parametre undefined. If I add both contracts and then compile the code, when I use

`var myContract = web3.eth.contract(masterContract.abi);`
won't this cause issues if the abi code includes that of subject and master contract together, but if I don't do this, compiler throws bunch of errors.

Another thing I have considered is using import statements before compilation, but not sure how to safely implement it. Please help out guys!

Comment: `@Varun` How did you get the `SubjectAddr`? I am having trouble  to import the contract by `SubjectContract subjectContract = SubjectContract(subjectAddr);` coz I want to it to get the the address by itself like using `Subject.deplyed().address` or something like this.

Comment: When compiling using browser solidity, you need to place both contracts together. The browser will generate separate byte code so you don't need to worry about it. I didn't understand your question entirely though.
As for the `subjectAddr`, it is a parametre that you need to know before hand and pass it like a regular expression.

Comment: `@Varun` I meant that because I have both the contracts in the same `*.sol ` file and I have to get `subjectAddr` for `SubjectContract subjectContract = SubjectContract(subjectAddr);`. So is there a command which I can use in solidity so that I don't have to insert the contract address in truffle or web3. something like the `.address `

Comment: Not that I know of. You see in my example the point of `SubjectContract subjectContract = SubjectContract(subjectAddr);` was to reference an existing contract at a known address and inspect its values. So if there are 100 such contracts deployed, I want to be able to call each one separately and inspect its values from `Master` contract. If the contract address were not to be inserted, it defeats the purpose of my function. :)

Comment: Fair enough! But I still feel that if I have a single solidity file with multiple contracts they should be able to access the basic info such as the `address` of some other contract in that file.

Comment: No, you can access it irrespective of if its in the same `.sol` file or not. In fact I think you mgiht not be able to access address of another contract if its in the same as file as the main contract. Please test this using browser solidity or a testnet, cause I am pretty sure you won't be able to. Let me know if you can though.

Answer (score 6):

What you need to do is to define the interface of the `SubjectContract` contract so that the `Master` contract can compile.

Here is your `Master` contract with the `SubjectContract` interface, along with a few minor changes:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract SubjectContract {
    function increaseCount() returns (uint newCount);
}

contract Master {
    bool public isActive=false;
    uint public num=0;

    function changeState() returns (bool newState) {
        isActive = !isActive;
        newState = isActive;
    }

    function increaseSubjectCount(address subjectAddr) returns (uint newCount) {
        SubjectContract subjectContract = SubjectContract(subjectAddr);
        newCount = subjectContract.increaseCount();
    }
}
```

Separately you will have to deploy the following `SubjectContract` with a few minor changes:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

contract SubjectContract {
    uint public count = 0;

    function increaseCount() returns (uint newCount) {
        count ++;
        newCount = count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok so to compile master contract, I would copy paste, what you have written into browser-solidity and compile it. But now when I do `let myContract = web3.eth.contract(MasterContract.abi)` and execute this, the abi code has the word `contract` used twice, so how does web3js know I want to create the master contract and subject contract is just an interface? Won't there be confusion regarding this?

Comment: Refer to http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/understanding-tokencreator-ownedtoken-example-from-solidity-documentation/7489#7489 . You will see the there is a separate abiDefinition for TokenCreator and OwnedToken . Your will similarly have separate ABIs for the different contracts.

Comment: Yes, when I compile in solc, I get one abi. But If I have 3 contracts that are inter-dependent on each other, then do I place all three together in browser-solidity and compile it three times such that I get three different abi ?